# AppleScript: Show a service when right clicking empty space in Finder

Tags: applescript

When right clicking files or folders (if your Automator service is configured this way), you can get  a service to appear.

How can I get a service to appear if I right click on empty space?

Note: I have included no code/pictures because I can't find any kind of reference to get started.

Answer (score 0):

From my experience you have to have some kind of input for a right click. With out more information on what you are trying to do this is hard to help you with. Best bet is if there is no input then just set the input to anything and just ignore the input in the steps. This way you can select anything and just have it run.